# Error in `/.default`(residuals, sigmas) : non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, bootstrap-modal, forecast, volatility

I am trying to run a garch model and to forecast the variance and then calculate the prices of an index by using bootstrapping. Therefore, I got:

```
garchspec1 <- ugarchspec( mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)),
                     variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH"),
                     distribution.model = "norm")
garchfit1 <- ugarchfit(data = SP500returns , spec = garchspec)
garchforecast1 <- ugarchforecast(fitORspec = garchfit, n.ahead = 20)

sigmas = sigma(garchforecast1)
residuals  = residuals(garchfit1)


nus = residuals/sigmas
```

When I try to divide residuals/sigmas,  I got this error.